# With Worpress and theme Divi some field types of profile can't work

Tags: wordpress, profile, autocomplete

I worked to build a form with two Autocomplete-Select fields, the one in which the description Search by name / email or id appears ..., but unfortunately now it does not work in public pages, but only in the WP dashboard. On the public side there is a theme made with Divi. Is it possible that there is incompatibility between the javascript of Divi and Civicrm? What could I try to make the profile work? I can't change the field format, they are a reference contact lists with the names of two groups

Comment: Welcome to SE! In what way does it not work? - Is anything of the profile displayed? - Is the autocomplete box shown? - Does it just not get back any data? - Does it work when logged in as admin? - Is it any different if you try with a standard theme? Open your browser's developer tools and see if there are any javascript errors, and check whether there is network activity when you type into the autocomplete. It's possible there is a javascript problem. It could also be a permissions problem.

Comment: Thank you Aidan for your suggestions. Now I have a second issue: I can see and compile the two autocomplete fields but only if I am logged. Anonymous users can't see these fields visiting the page. Where do I find the privacy selectors to show they in this public profile?

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved turning off some javascripts in the Divi options. This is switch is a very good thing.